# Showing YUV420p using pygame overlay leads to green bar on top of image

Tags: python, pygame, overlay

The code is as follows. Image is decoded by PyAV library. On top of picture there is a horizontal green bar. Probably 1 pixel height. Do you have any idea how to avoid that? I have seen lots of recomendations for VLC player to disable hardware acceleration. It is already disabled in pygame. I work in Windows10 64bit.

```
import av
import pygame
import time

container = av.open('video.mp4') # libx264 en-/decoded, pixel format yuv420p
container.streams.video[0].thread_type = 'AUTO'
frameSequence = container.decode(video=0)
for _ in range(100):
    image = next(frameSequence) #skip some frames
pygame.init()
trueResolution = pygame.display.list_modes()[0]  # corresponds to video, as it FULL HD
                                                 #also tested with HD
pygame.display.set_mode(trueResolution)
ovl = pygame.Overlay(pygame.YV12_OVERLAY,trueResolution)
ovl.display((image.planes[0], image.planes[1], image.planes[2]))
time.sleep(10)
```

I have also tried to replace first lines in every plane by other lines, to check whether the image is corrupted. Results are the same, so the image seems to be correct.

UPD1. The link to video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t6d5weBVeW4EWzGI1gytmUBwXF91dNC9/view?usp=sharing

The screenshot with a green line on top of the image
[image: The screenshot with a green line on top of the image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we are able to replicate your problem and try to help. In your code snippet, `image` is defined elsewhere.

Comment: @Eric I have edited the code. Now it's full working example

Comment: Thanks for the edit, are you able to upload your source video or an image so we can run your example code?

Comment: @Eric the link to video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t6d5weBVeW4EWzGI1gytmUBwXF91dNC9/view?usp=sharing
trueResolution has to be (1280,720) in such a case

Comment: @Eric I have added a screenshot also. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for the sample, I was able to replicate your problem. If you change the Overlay format to `IYUV_OVERLAY` the colours are wrong (blue), but the green line is unchanged. To me that indicates some problem with the setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce to screen size and change the location of the overlay to hide the green bars. I know this is not a fix, but you might find it good enough to progress further.

The documentation for Overlay does warn:

> The Overlay objects represent lower level access to the display
>   hardware. To use the object you must understand the technical details
>   of video overlays.

So someone with more domain expertise might be able to provide a better solution.

```
pygame.display.set_mode((1280,  718), pygame.RESIZABLE)
ovl = pygame.Overlay(pygame.YV12_OVERLAY,trueResolution)
ovl.set_location(pygame.Rect(0,-2,1280, 720))
```

Note also `trueResolution` should be determined from the source stream rather than the [full screen modes](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.list_modes) supported by the graphics card.

Also the `image` in this case is a [VideoFrame](http://docs.mikeboers.com/pyav/develop/api/video.html#module-av.video.frame), you can use its `.to_image()` method to convert to a PIL type image or `.to_rgb()`, which might be easier to display if you don't want/need to use an Overlay.

Comment: Thanks a lot, probably in pygame 2 it will be solved in a better way.
Avoiding .to_rgb() is exactly what I try using pygame overlay. .to_rgb() is to slow for full HD. Parsing is longer than frame period even with a good cpu.